# Derivative of $\arcsin(\cos x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

In my calculus course, my teacher asked me to differentiate the function
$$f(x) = \arcsin(\cos x).$$
My work looked like so,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}\cdot-\sin x
= -\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x}}
= -\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|} = -\frac{|\sin x|}{\sin x}.
$$
However, as I went to confirm my answer with my instructor, they claimed that my answer was incorrect. Instead, they claimed my work should have gone like so:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}\cdot-\sin x
= -\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x}}
= -\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}
= -1.
$$ I attempted to explain how I thought $\sqrt{x^2}$ simplified to $|x|$, but they keep asserting I'm incorrect, claiming that the function $\arcsin x$ does not exist for $|x|>\frac{\pi}{2}$, and that therefore $-1$ should indeed be the correct answer within the domain of the function, which they said was $|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

This has just left my confused about the whole matter. Can anyone explain which derivative is right here, and why?

Comment: Did your instructor mean $0 < x < \pi/2$ instead of $|x| < \pi/2$? Because otherwise for $-\pi/2 < x < 0$ $\arcsin(\cos(x))$ is definitely increasing with derivative $+1$ not $-1$ as your instructor claimed. Also the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Your instructor is wrong. It doesn't matter that $\arcsin x$ is undefined for $|x|>\tfrac{\pi}{2}$  because you're not applying $\arcsin$ to $x$, but to $\cos x$ which is always between $-1$ and $1$, where the $\arcsin$ IS defined.  By the way, the domain of $\arcsin$ is NOT $|x|< \tfrac{\pi}{2}$ , is $|x|\le 1$

Comment: If your instructor is saying that $f'(x)=-1$ for all $x$ in $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$, then this is clearly wrong because it means $f$ is always strictly decreasing, which is impossible since $f$ is even.

Comment: Also in case you want visuals, here is a wolfram plot: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arcsin%28cos%28x%29%29+between+-pi%2F2+and+pi%2F2

Comment: Another plot of the function: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9vkuq2kt2y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}$ and not $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ because the domain of the cosine function is $\mathbb{R}$ and the range is $[-1,1]$, and so the $\arcsin$ function doesn't limit the domain of $f$. Your derivative simplifies to:

$$f'(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        -1, & \text{for } x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi)\\
        1, & \text{for } x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} ((2n+1)\pi,(2n+2)\pi).
        \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a simplification over $-\frac{|\sin x|}{\sin x}$ 